# How do I add a load game functionality in my game on c++

Tags: c++, game-development

I am developing a c++ story game in which you are a car dealer and want to add a save game and load game functionality. I have added the save game feature using fstream library. Could someone please explain me a better way to add load game feature without putting too many `goto` functions or `if else` statements.
I am posting the game code below, I know it is not flawless nor complete at this moment but I just want to know the solution to my issue.
This is the main file

```cpp
//Vehicle Shop Sim
//All dialogues are normal text
//All scene setting text is italics text
//All choices are in bold
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "classAndObjects.hpp"
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
ifstream playerDetailsBring("userDetails.txt");
ofstream playerDetailsSave("userDetails.txt");

ifstream emilyBring("emily.txt");
ofstream emilySave("emily.txt");

ifstream oscarBring("oscar.txt");
ofstream oscarSave("oscar.txt");

ifstream oliverBring("oliver.txt");
ofstream oliverSave("oliver.txt");

ifstream harperBring("harper.txt");
ofstream harperSave("harper.txt");

/*inline void defObjects(void)
{
    oscar.name = "Oscar";
    oscar.salary = 35000;

    oliver.name = "Oliver";
    oliver.salary = 31000;

    harper.name = "Harper";
    harper.salary = 36000;

    emily.name = "Emily";
    emily.salary = 32000;
}*/
int main()
{
    // void defObjects(void);
    oscar.name = "Oscar";
    oscar.salary = 35000;
    oscar.id = 1;

    oliver.name = "Oliver";
    oliver.salary = 31000;
    oliver.id = 2;

    harper.name = "Harper";
    harper.salary = 36000;
    harper.id = 3;

    emily.name = "Emily";
    emily.salary = 32000;
    emily.id = 4;

    nate.name = "Nate";
    nate.nature = trustworthy;

    emilySave << emily.name << endl
              << emily.salary << endl
              << emily.id << endl;
    harperSave << harper.name << endl
               << harper.salary << endl
               << harper.id << endl;
    oscarSave << oscar.name << endl
              << oscar.salary << endl
              << oscar.id << endl;
    oliverSave << oliver.name << endl
               << oliver.salary << endl
               << oliver.id;
    cls();
    type("Hello! This is the Vehicle Dealer Simulator");
    el();
    type("Type yes or no when questioned");
    el();
    type("Enter dealer's (your) name: ");
    getline(cin, player.name);
    type("So, you entered your name as Nincompoop, right? ");
    string zorx;
    while (true)
    {
        getline(cin, zorx);
        if (zorx[0] == 'n' || zorx[0] == 'N')
        {
            type("Okay then, please re enter your name: ");
            while (true)
            {
                getline(cin, player.name);
                if (player.name.size() > 40)
                {
                    type("Name too long, try again: ");
                }
                if (player.name.size() < 4)
                {
                    type("Name too short, try again: ");
                }
                
            }
            playerDetailsSave << "player name: " << player.name << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (zorx[0] == 'y' || zorx[0] == 'Y')
        {
            player.name = "Nincompoop";
            playerDetailsSave << "player name: " << player.name << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (zorx[0] != 'y' && zorx[0] != 'Y' && zorx[0] != 'n' && zorx[0] != 'N')
        {
            type("Invalid anwer, try again: ");
        }
    }
    cls();
    type("Enter your company's name: ");
    el();
    while (true)
    {
        getline(cin, userCompany.name);
        if (4 < userCompany.name.size() < 40)
            break;
        if (userCompany.name.size() > 40)
        {
            type("Company name too long (max 40 characters), try again: ");
        }
        if (userCompany.name.size() < 4)
        {
            type("Company name too short (min 4 characters), try again: ");
        }
    }
    playerDetailsSave << "company's name: " << userCompany.name << endl;
    getch();
    cls();
    cout << userCompany.name;
    type(" has been going bankcurpt due to unpopularity, heavy competetion and many other reasons");
    getch();
    cls();
    type("Lets start with a little tour of your shop ");
    el();
    type("Your shop has 3 rooms - \nThe storage room where all parts are stored\nOne work room where all the work is done");
    el();
    type("And the final room is your personal office where you spend time thinking and meeting with dealers and interviewing new emplyees");
    el();
    type("But don't worry because you can buy or sell land to change your shop in future ;)");
    getch();
    cls();
    type("As of now, ");
    cout << userCompany.name;
    type(" has 3 employees: ");
    el();
    cout << oscar.name;
    type(" salary :");
    cout << oscar.salary;
    el();
    cout << oliver.name;
    type(" salary :");
    cout << oliver.salary;
    el();
    cout << harper.name;
    type(" salary :");
    cout << harper.salary;
    el();
    cout << emily.name;
    type(" salary :");
    cout << emily.salary;
    el();
    getch();
    cls();
    type("So lets begin...");
    getch();
    cls();
    cout << player.name;
    typeI(" is sitting in his office thinking about a christmas schemes");
    el();
    typeI("A tall man with a groomed beard enters");
    el();
    type("The person: Hello! I am Nate and I own Auto Supplies limited.");
    el();
    cout << player.name;
    typeI(" offers him a seat and orders a coffee");
    el();
    type("Nate: Auto Supplies limited is an enterprise which produces automobile accessories");
    el();
    type("Nate: I got to know about you from a customer who said that he got his car ");
    type("serviced in your company and wanted a back camera for his brand new jeep");
    el();
    type("Nate: I have come with partnership interests with you ");
    el();
    choices3("accept Nate as a partner dealer", "refuse him", "delay him and ask for time to think");
    cin>>zorx;
    
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be needing many conditionals, and no gotos whatsoever. It's very difficult to advise without seeing what you did.

Comment: @molbdnilo please check, now I have posted the code as well

Comment: You don't need to "tag" everything in the save file. If you save "id, newline, name, newline, salary, newline" for each player, it get almost trivial to read.

Comment: One option is to represent your story arc as a directed graph.  The nodes in the graph are the story elements, and the player decisions are the edges between nodes.  The graph itself can contain the game state in a simplistic game.  And so the current node is the only thing required to store the player's progress.  In a more complex game, a separate "game state" may influence player choices or available options, in which case that game state is also part of the information that should be persisted.

Comment: On a side note, opening every file twice - once for reading and once for writing - is not going to work. The sooner you lose the habit of using global variables, the better. (And read more about file handling in your favourite C++ book, and do some exercises.)

Comment: @paddy Actually I am not really an experienced coder. Could you explain what is a directed graph and a node?

Comment: @molbdnilo what else can I do else open every file twice because I do need to modify and read every file

Comment: Open files when you need them. When you start, open for reading and read. When you need to save, open for writing and write. (And do get into the habit of writing functions. Otherwise, you're going to write yourself into a massive mess of code and bugs soon.)

Comment: @QwertyPrasad A directed graph is an extremely common data structure / paradigm in computer programming.  You can find plenty of information out there.  Perhaps this is beyond your experience, or perhaps it's just challenging enough for you to tackle and level up.  I think it's important to learn about new stuff.  I remember almost 30 years ago a friend at school telling me about linked lists, I went home and wrote a crappy one in C and it blew my mind open.  So, read about graphs and think about how you could potentially represent your entire game as a series of states connected by decisions.

Comment: Expanding on the above, since I ran out of characters... If this is a purely story-based game like a "pick-a-path" book, then most likely your program can be extremely small, and the game itself can just be a simple text file with a particular format.  You can then write new stories and run them in the same program.  I wouldn't be surprised if some standard format for this kind of thing already exists.

Comment: @paddy Okay, thank you very much. I will surely read on the terms you introduced me to.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer, but can't post this as a comment.

Try to organize your code a bit. It's all in a single function. Hard to read, hard to modified. You have three main routines: playing the game, saving the state, and loading the state of the game. Loading takes places at the start, saving at the end. Therefore, try to organize it as following:

```cpp
void save_game() 
{
  /* do the saving */
}

void load_game()
{
  /* do the loading */
}

void play_game()
{
  /* do the playing */
}
```

Then, your `main()` would simply look like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
  load_game();
  play_game();
  save_game();
}
```

Of course, you could ask the user whether to load or save the game state. If you do so, add more functions. Here is an example:

```cpp
bool should_load_game()
{
  char option;
  std::cout << "Load game? (/Y/N): ";
  std::cin >> option;
  return option == 'y' || option == 'Y';
}

bool should_save_game()
{
  char option;
  std::cout << "Save game? (/Y/N): ";
  std::cin >> option;
  return option == 'y' || option == 'Y';
}
```

Then, your main will change as follows:

```cpp
int main()
{
  if(should_load_game())
     load_game();

  play_game();

  if(should_save_game())
     save_game();
}
```

See, this is already getting simpler, and people can read your code.

How, you have everything in global variables. That is fine for a small program when you want to learn things. But not good in general. So the next step would be to define the data you need to pass from one function to the other in a local place and pass it as arguments. Or you can put everything here in a class and define the global as data members.